# Positive Negative - Simple Python exercise

Tags: python

Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.

I finally figured it out.

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b < 0)
  else:
    return (a > 0 and b < 0) or (a < 0 and b > 0)
```

But... why do I return those two lines instead of True? How do I know to do this in a similar situation?

Comment: What do you mean by _"why do I return those two lines instead of True"_? You're not _supposed_ to return `True`, you're supposed to return whether or not the condition is fulfilled. If the function only returned `True`, what would be the point of it?

Comment: Like I can't think of (a < 0 and b < 0) as True. Logic-wise, that's not what I think first.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning those two lines. You are returning the values that those two lines *evaluate to*. In your cases, those are boolean expressions that will evaluate to either true or false. That final boolean value is what your function returns.

Comment: Thanks! Is this always the case in a situation like this so I should not use True or False?

Comment: It is better style to do this. You can always put your expressions into if statements and return literal true or literal false, but it is more cumbersome to do that. Instead of saying "If this is true, return true, else return false", your function says, "Return whether this is true or not".

Comment: Ahh...okay. I kind of get it.

Comment: This isn't proper simply because you never have the ability to return false which can and will lead to a potential failure down the line it would be easier to return True and False based on both conditions. As in if negative == True and both numbers are positive return True or if one number is negative and the other positive return false.

Answer (score 1):

Python evaluates whatever expression follows the `return` statement, and the result of the evaluation is what is returned.  You have used two boolean expressions:

```
(a < 0 and b < 0)
```

This evaluates to True if both a < 0 and b < 0; otherwise it evaluates to False

```
(a > 0 and b < 0) or (a < 0 and b > 0)
```

This evaluates to True if either of the parentheses evaluate to True; otherwise it evaluates to False

which is what you want. So `pos_neg` automatically returns either True or False depending on the specified inputs.

Perhaps you were thinking of testing each condition for True/False, then using an `if` statement to `return True` if the condition is True and to `return False` if the condition is False. That would work, but would be unnecessarily long and complex. Here, you are just returning with whatever the boolean value of each expression works out to be, whether it's `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_group(number):
   if number > 0:
      return "Positive"
   elif number < 0:
      return "negative"
   else:
      return "zero"

print(number_group(10)) #Should be Positive
print(number_group(0)) #Should be Zero
print(number_group(-5)) #Should be Negative
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_group(number):
  if number>0:
    return "Positive"
  elif number==0:
    return "Zero"
  else:
    return("Negative")

print(number_group(10)) #Should be Positive
print(number_group(0)) #Should be Zero
print(number_group(-5)) #Should be Negative
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).